# Python - Web Scraping exercise - Attribute Error

Tags: python, spyder

I am learning how to scrape web information. Below is a snippet of the actual code solution + output from datacamp.

[image]

On datacamp, this works perfectly fine, but when I try to run it on Spyder (my own macbook), it doesn't work...

This is because on datacamp, the URL has already been pre-loaded into a variable named 'response'.. however on Spyder, the URL needs to be defined again.

So, I first defined the response variable as **response = requests.get('https://www.datacamp.com/courses/all')** so that the code will point to datacamp's website..

My code looks like:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.datacamp.com/courses/all')

this_url = response.url

this_title = response.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract_first()

print_url_title( this_url, this_title )
```

When I run this on Spyder, I got an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-6a8340fd3a71>", line 11, in <module>
    this_title = response.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract_first()

AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

Could someone please guide me? I would really like to know how to get this code working on Spyder.. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by `requests.get('https://www.datacamp.com/courses/all')` is a [`Response` object](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.1.0/user/quickstart/#make-a-request), and this object has no attribute `xpath`, hence the error: `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'xpath'`

I assume `response` from your tutorial source, probably has been assigned to another object (most likely the object returned by `etree.HTML`) and not the value returned by `requests.get(url)`.

You can however do this:

```
from lxml import etree  #import etree
response = requests.get('https://www.datacamp.com/courses/all') #get the Response object
tree = etree.HTML(response.text) #pass the page's source using the Response object
result = tree.xpath('/html/head/title/text()') #extract the value
print(response.url) #url
print(result)  #findings
```